# Where to find DB2 Java Stored procedure system output?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2

A Java program is bundled into a jar and deployed to DB2. It's deployed as stored procedure and it works fine.

The question is: where would we look for messages output via  `System.out.println("debug message");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere.
[Restrictions on external routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0009198.html):

> Receiving inputs from the keyboard and displaying outputs to standard
> output is not possible from external routines. Do not use standard
> input-output streams. For example:
>
> - In external Java™ routine code, do not issue the System.out.println() methods.
> - In external C or C++ routine code, do not issue printf().